# Access token lifetime when tokens are client certificate constrained

Tags: oauth2, openid-connect

When we use mTLS we can use access tokens constrained to client certificate that was sent to token endpoint to receive the access token. In this case, if only the client that send this request can use this access token even if access token leaks, is there any reason to use access token with lifetime? Isn't it better to use permanent access tokens in such a situation and get rid of refresh tokens?

Comment: Who provides the client certification? How is the access token constrained to it?

Comment: How do you manage the logoff function, do you have a list of certificates that are considered valid?

Comment: I think that it can be a self-signed certificate or issued by any CA (and then I check if the certificate is revoked by the CA). But the most important thing is that OIDC provider stores allowed certificate thumbprints for client. The issued access token could contain claim "thumbprint" that value is equal to certificate thumbprint used in token endpoint. Then any API need to verify this claim with received certificate.

Comment: Assuming that by thumbprint you mean a hash (message digest), you mean that an access token refers to a valid hash of a certificate? Or that the token is signed by a certificate, whose hash is included in the token?

Comment: Yes, access token contain valid hash of certificate (and access token is signed by OIDC provider). Then to use this access token, API shall authenticate requestor with mTLS and compare received thumbprint with thumbprint contained in access token.

Comment: when you say "better", from which point of view? E.g. security? management? something else?

Comment: I think it's better because we don't have to use refresh tokens and it's just easier to manage it in client app. But I didn't actually think that the scopes for the client might change. In addition, the client certificate may change, and then we would have to log out all users. So it seems refresh token is necessary.